# How do I get an index from items in a grid layout?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I know that my question is quite weird but here is the code that I have come up with:

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QWidget,  QDialog, QGridLayout,
                               QLabel, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QApplication)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QIcon)
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt,Slot )

labelss = ["a","b","aaze","12a","va","lz7a","a","n","a","b",]
        
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        btn = QPushButton()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.show_remove_label_dialog)

        self.setCentralWidget(btn)

        self.setGeometry(600, 100, 1000, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Scroll Area Demonstration')
        self.show()
    @Slot()
    def show_remove_label_dialog(self):
        global dialog2
        dialog2 = RemoveLabelDialog()
        dialog2.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Then we have a remove dialog class:

```py
class RemoveLabelDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.index_list = []
        self.labels = labelss
        self.setWindowTitle("Remove labels")

        self.dialog_layout = QVBoxLayout() #contains remove button and scroll area
        self.scroll_area   = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll_area.setMaximumHeight(200)
        self.scroll_widget = QWidget()
        self.scroll_layout = QGridLayout()

        for u in range(len(self.labels)):
            self.label = QLabel(self.labels[u])
            self.check = QCheckBox()
            self.check.toggled.connect(self.check_toggled)
            self.scroll_layout.addWidget(self.label, u, 0)
            self.scroll_layout.addWidget(self.check, u, 1)
        
        self.scroll_widget.setLayout(self.scroll_layout)
        self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.scroll_widget)

        self.remove_selected_button_icon = QIcon("gui/assets/icons/trash.svg")
        self.remove_selected_button = QPushButton(self.remove_selected_button_icon, "Remove selected")

        self.dialog_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.dialog_layout.addWidget(self.remove_selected_button)
        self.setLayout(self.dialog_layout)

    @Slot()
    def check_toggled(self, index):
        if checkbox_turned_on:
            self.index_list.append(index)
        elif checkbox_turned_off:
            self.index_list.remove(index)
            
        # do some other backend logic with the index_list...
```

Basically what I want is so that when u toggle on a check box, it adds the index of the associated label in the labelss list to a list, and when you toggle off a check box, it removes said index from the list.
I do not know how I could pass in a slot the index of the check box:

say for example whe want to toggle the first and second to last check box only, the check_toggled would then be called getting in an index (this does not work) of the associated check box and then it either add or removes the index to the index_list list. So basically toggling them both for the first time would give the list [0, 8]. Then say we untoggle the first item, this list would then become [8].

I do not know how you could do the for loop to adapt to a dynamic amount of elements in the labelss list, neither do I know how you would implement the slot with if elif statement conditions

Comment: Use a lambda with keyword arguments (otherwise it will always use the latest occurrence of the index in the loop): `self.check.toggled.connect(lambda _, index=index: self.check_toggled(index))`. Note that setting instance attributes (like `self.label`) in a for loop is completely pointless. Just use a local variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that. Yes thank I will change that...